# SplashScreen everytime I'm back on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I'm using this code on MainActivity for a splashscreen that works perfectly

```
final ImageView splash1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            splash1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

but everytime I'm back on MainActivity (where the main menu is), the splashScreen is there again. Is there a way to keep using this code, and just adding an if condition do not see the splashScreen after the first time?
(e.g: a variable that changes when the app loads)
Thanks in advance

Comment: are your using two separate activity ? Or your splash screen is just an image

Comment: Where did you put these currently ?

Comment: Where starting next activity?

Comment: The code is on MainActivity and the SplashScreen is just an image

Comment: Which method of MainActivity ?

Comment: finish() SplashActivity before starting new Activity

Comment: You can save a boolean value in SharedPrefs, and based on that value can show the splashscreen only once.

Comment: Recommended use different activity for splash.

Comment: @Anandroid if i would do so, wouldnt I have the SplashScreen only once, the first time i start the app? when I start the app again, i wouldnt have it anymore

Comment: @Giuseppe, Sorry thats right, In that case you can save it in an application level variable (Extending a class with Application), So that the value will be there untill the app is running(foreground or background).

Comment: Would a `static boolean` class variable help? @Giuseppe

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 different activity SplashActivity and MainActivity.

Your "Splash" activity need to be MAIN LAUNCHER Activity. So modify the AndroidManifest file like this...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And Jump to MainActivity from SplashActivity after few seconds.. Use this code in SplashActivity.

```
Handler hadler=new Handler();
        hadler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

here 3000 is used for 3 seconds. The MainActivity auto start after 3 seconds. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate activity for splash screen after that go for MainActivity, Don't forget to use finish() in splash screen activity.

This link may help you

http://androidexample.com/Splash_screen_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=113&aaid=135

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one variable to know whether its displayed or not.

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {

    boolean isDisplayed;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (!isDisplayed) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isDisplayed = true;
                    splash1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            splash1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `finish()` after starting the `SplashScreen` Activity

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

One more approach can be - Create a boolean application level variable (set to false) by extending `Application`class & then checking it in the `run`method - If false then show the splash & set it to true, so that it will not execute again.

```
public class DefaultApplication extends Application {
  private boolean isSplashDisplayed = false;

  public boolean isSplashDisplayed() {
     return isSplashDisplayed ;
  }

  public void setIsSplashDisplayed(boolean isSplashDisplayed) {
     this.isSplashDisplayed = isSplashDisplayed;
  }
}
```

Second Approach - 
Its better to create a separate activity for Splash, then call MainActivity from SplashActivity & finish SplashActivity

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Also need to make your SplashActivity as launcher

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >>     
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />>     
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    < /activity>
```